# Function returning the first initialization of the variables, not the overwritten ones

Tags: python, function

```
def hand():
    print("Wrong port format")
    er()

def er():
    try:
            host=input("Host: ")
            serverPort=(input("Port: "))
            try:
                Port=int(serverPort) 
            except Exception:
                hand()
            return (host,int(serverPort))
    except Exception:
            return("Wrong")

serverPorti=er()

print((serverPorti))
```

When I run it returns Wrong, I want the user to input the host and the port but if the user inputs a text(letters) in port number it should call back the function er(), it does call back but the return even after I input the right port number returns wrong.

Comment: Get rid of the try/except and look at the traceback. If you can't make sense of it, post it in your question. Your blanket except is hiding the details for all of us.

Comment: @roganjosh I got rid of it and the variables host and  severPort still have the same values as I input in the first time not the ones after  reinvoking the function, so the serverPort still has the text value that I input at first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i am bored i made it working for you

```
def getHostPort():
    host = ''
    serverPort = ''
    inputCorrect = False

    while not inputCorrect:
        try:
            host = input("Host: ")
            serverPort = int(input("Port: "))
            inputCorrect = True
        except Exception:
            print("wrong port")
            continue

    return (host,int(serverPort))

serverPorti=getHostPort()
print((serverPorti))
```

Comment: edited and made it work, remember python version lower then 3 use raw_input instead of input, may i also note your question has nothing to do with socket programming itself ;)

Comment: That's just perfectly working, Thank you!, Yes you're right I am programming a server-client socket so my bad

Comment: as you can see a while loop is better for fetching correct user input from terminal

Comment: Yes thanks and I changed the tittle hope it is more adjustable with the question